# Driving fan 4 pin with low frequency PWM

Tags: pwm, fan

I currently using a [4pin fan](https://noctua.at/en/nf-a14-pwm) in my project.

I need to drive the fan with a 120 Hz PWM signal. I read in all the documentation of the fan that the suitable PWM frequency is from 21 to 28 kHz.

I tested the fan using the 120Hz signal and it seems to work well.

Do you think that my configuration can be safe? Is there something that can go wrong driving the fan in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer gives a suitable frequency range above 20 kHz to avoid a buzzing of the fan in the audible frequency range. As long as you don't mind this or your setup does not even produce any hum you will be fine.